# Android: Image transparent mask around the badge

Tags: android, imageview, mask

What is the best way to make a mask like this (around the badge):

[image]

Now it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to just have the Image already with these cut outs tbh especially the rounded parts at the top right and left bottom arent easy.

Alternatively you can create a Bitmap mask like you want and do some canvas magic with Porter Duff Mode source Out or destination Out.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode

Comment: Of course the backend won't send me done image. It will be so easy) But thanks for the advice. I've already known about it. Some developers recommend BitmapShader.